# Every finite-dimensional subspace is one-complemented

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. It is known that if every closed subspace of $X$ is one-complemented, then $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Now if every finite-dimensional subspace of $X$ is one-complemented, is it true that is $X$ isometrically isomorphic to a Hilbert space?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain (or link to an explanation of) what "one-complemented" means.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I suppose one-complemented means "complemented by projection of norm one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this is true and you may restrict yourself to two-dimensional subspaces! That is, $X$ is isometric to a Hilbert space if and only if every two-dimensional subspace is 1-complemented. This is due to Kakutani (1939) in the real case, and Bohnenblust (1941) in the complex case.

**References:**

> P. Bohnenblust, [A characterization of complex Hilbert spaces](http://purl.pt/2111/2/j-5293-b-vol3-fasc2-art5_PDF/j-5293-b-vol3-fasc2-art5_PDF_08-G-R0150/j-5293-b-vol3-fasc2-art5_0000_capa-109_t08-G-R0150.pdf), *Portugaliae Math.*, **3** (1942), 103–109.
>
> S. Kakutani, [Some characterizations of Euclidean space](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjm1924/16/0/16_0_93/_article), *Japan. J. Math*. **16** (1939), 93–97.

Comment: Good references!

Answer (score 1):

*It is known that if every closed subspace of X is one-complemented, then X is isometrically isomorphic to a Hilbert space.*

This is true for spaces of dimension at least three, right? So, the argument of Norbert does not work. You can not prove that a two dimensional vector space is a Hilbert space by proving that all the one dimensional subspaces are one-complemented.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of result you stated. I take it for granted.

Thanks to the parallelogram law it is enough to show that any two-dimensional subspace is a Hilbert space. Now take any two-dimensional subspace $E$ of $X$. From assumption any $1$-dimensional subspace of $E$ is one-complemented in $X$ and a fortiori in $E$. Therefore, from result you stated in the beginning of the question we get that $E$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: No need to take it for granted :-)